# chemical reaction, arrow misplaced

Tags: chemfig, chemistry

I am new on latex and on chemfig.
Here are the molecules that I would like to draw. My problem is that I can't put the arrow where I would like it to be. I have tried with the anchors but apparently the rectangle in which I draw my molecules are all mess up, I don't know why...

Here is my code, hope that you can help me.

1st reaction:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
\setchemfig{scheme debug=true}
%1st reaction
\schemestart[][]    
\chemname{\chemfig{F-[:-90]*6(-=-(-B([::60]-OH)-[::-60]OH)=(-F)-=N)}}{}         
\arrow(--[yshift=-80pt]){0}[,0]\+{0pt,20pt,60pt}
\chemname{\chemfig{Br-[:90]*6(=N-=-=-)}}{}  
\arrow(.north east--.west){->[5\% mol Pd(OAc)\textsubscript2,  PPh\textsubscript3][THF/H\textsubscript2O, K\textsubscript2CO\textsubscript3, 80C, Ar]}[0,3]
\chemname{\chemfig{F-[:-90]*6(-N=(-F)-([:-90]-*6(-=-=-N=))=-=)}}{}
\schemestop
%    
%2nd reaction 
\setchemfig{scheme debug=true}
\schemestart[][center]
\chemname{\chemfig{OCH\textsubscript3-[:-90]*6(-=-(-B([::60]-OH)-[::-60]OH)=-=)}}{4-methoxyphenyl boronic acid}          
\arrow(--[yshift=-80pt]){0}[,0]\+{0pt,10pt,60pt}
\chemname{\chemfig{Br-[:90]*6(=N-=-=-)}}{2-bromo pyridine}               
\arrow(.east--.west){->[5\% Pd(OAc)\textsubscript2,  PPh                    \textsubscript3][EtOH/Toluene/H\textsubscript2O, K\textsubscript2CO\textsubscript3, 110C, Ar]}[0,2]
\chemname{\chemfig{OCH\textsubscript3-[:-90]*6(-=-([:-90]-*6(-=-=-N=))=-=)}}{}
\schemestop
\end{document}
```

thank you

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Plase make your code a complete, compilable document, so that it's easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to TeX.SE. The second molecule (`c2`) is shorter than the first molecule (`c1`), but `c2` inherits the height of the `c1` molecule making it too tall. This inheritance can be prevented by executing `\chemnameinit` immediately after drawing the first molecule. Thereafter, the arrows and remaining molecules in the sequence are vertically aligned without the need to resort to shifting coordinates manually.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}
\setchemfig{scheme debug=true}
\schemestart[][]
\chemname{\chemfig{F-[:-90]*6(-=-(-B([::60]-OH)-[::-60]OH)=(-F)-=N)}}{\phantom{M}}
\chemnameinit{}  % <-- added this
\arrow(.east--.west)
\chemname{\chemfig{Br-[:90]*6(=N-=-=-)}}{}
\arrow(.east--.west){->[5\% mol Pd(OAc)\textsubscript{2},  PPh\textsubscript3][THF/H\textsubscript{2}O, K\textsubscript{2}CO\textsubscript{3}, 80C, Ar]}[0,3]
\chemname{\chemfig{F-[:-90]*6(-N=(-F)-([:-90]-*6(-=-=-N=))=-=)}}{}
\schemestop
\end{document}
```

[image]